# anonymous javascript function call !function vs function

Tags: javascript

How come

```
function(){ alert("test123");}()
```

produces `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

while

```
!function(){ alert("test123");}()
```

alerts "test123"

?

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @zerkms You should probably post that as an answer, as it actually explains the heart of the matter quite well.

Comment: c'mon, there _has_ to be a duplicate...

Comment: @Kippie: link-only answers aren't welcomed here :-)

Comment: @zerkms what about heavy quoting?

Comment: For even more fun. Anything that must be evaluated in an expression also does this: `-function(){}()`, `+function(){}()`,`0|function(){}()` etc

Comment: The most evil has got to be `0?0:function(){}()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because by adding `!` sign you convert the declaration into an expression and invoke it immediately. 
By enclosing your function into brackets you will make first example working without errors:

```
(function(){ alert("test123");})()
```

To make it clearer you can think about first expression as something like:

```
if (false || !function(){ return false; }())
```

---

And as @zerkms noticed there is a complete explanation of [Immediately-invoking functions](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: too bad I can't write a proper answer, but... "identifier" is not the correct term. Rather the distinction is between a definition and an expression. The former cannot be immediately invoked.

Comment: Right track but wrong explanation. The ! converts the declaration into an expression.

Comment: I can define a function and _not_ invoke it: `!function(){alert("will not be called")}`